# Variable doesn't parse as string

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, text

**Problem**

I tried to extract the signal level for wifi in the following way, in a bash script (quotes seem to make no difference):

```
string="$(iwconfig wlan0 | grep -I Signal)"
```

If I `echo $string`, I get what I expect:

```
Link Quality=63/70 Signal level=-47dBm
```

But if I try to get a substring, `echo ${string:5}`, it returns the same thing.

---

**Debuging:**

If I paste the output of `wconfig wlan0 | grep -I Signal` directly into the variable: `string="Link Quality=63/70 Signal level=-47dBm"` then everything works as expected.

```sh
echo $string 
# Link Quality=63/70 Signal level=-47dBm
echo ${string:5}
# Quality=63/70 Signal level=-47dBm
```

---

**Question:** According to the internet, all bash variables are stored as character strings. Thus, the debugging result should have been the same as my original problem. Is there some reason it is not parsed as text in the original problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is because `echo $string` doesn't simply print the value of `string`; it first perform a *split+glob* operation - one of the consequences of which is that leading whitespace is elided:

```
$ string=$(iwconfig wls1 | grep Signal)
$ echo $string
Link Quality=38/70 Signal level=-72 dBm
```

whereas

```
$ echo "$string"
          Link Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm
```

We can see that there is a sequence of whitespace characters at the start of `$string` - in fact there are more than 5, so removing 5 still leaves a string with leading whitespace, which an unquoted substring expansion (`${string:5}`) also elides:

```
$ echo "${string:5}"
     Link Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm  
$ echo ${string:5}
Link Quality=38/70 Signal level=-72 dBm
```

For additional discussion see:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Comment: Tl;dr always quote your variables

Answer (score 6):

This works on my machine:

```
$ string="$(iwconfig wlp60s0 | grep -I Signal)"
$ echo $string
Link Quality=68/70 Signal level=-42 dBm
$ echo $string | cut -d' ' -f4,5
level=-42 dBm
```

- For your machine replace `wlp60s0` with `wlan0`.
- **Note** this is using Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 19.04 where there is a space between `42` and `dBm`. As such the `cut` command is instructed to print fields #4 and #5. In your question there is no space so I'm not sure what version you are using.

You could also use:

```
$ echo $string | cut -d'=' -f3
-42 dBm
```

- In this case `cut` is told to use `=` as field delimiter.

If you want to use `${string...}` though the correct syntax is:

```
$ echo ${string##*=}
-38 dBm

$ echo "${string##*=}"
-38 dBm
```

Either method will work to take the substring after the last `=`. The original method of `5` in your question I don't understand how it can work.